# Middleman asks if I want to use compass when starting a new project

Tags: ruby, git, bash, compass, middleman

I'm on a Windows 10 machine. I have Ruby installed through git bash. I also have `middleman` installed (v4.0.0). When I do `middleman init "name_of_project"` it asks me if I want to use compass and I get stuck.

```
$ middleman init newproject
run  git clone --depth 1 git://github.com/middleman/middleman-templates-default.git C:/Users/dedvv/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160130-11408-c7ch9s from "."
Cloning into 'C:/Users/dedvv/AppData/Local/Temp/d20160130-11408-c7ch9s'...
remote: Counting objects: 22, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (15/15), done.
remote: Total 22 (delta 0), reused 14 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (22/22), 6.07 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Checking connectivity... done.
exist
 create  .gitignore
create  Gemfile
create  config.rb
create  source/images/middleman-logo.svg
 create  source/index.html.erb
create  source/javascripts/all.js
create  source/layouts/layout.erb
create  source/stylesheets/_normalize.scss
create  source/stylesheets/site.css.scss
Do you want to use Compass?
```

I have no idea what to do here in order to move on. `y/n yes/no` + <kbd>Enter</kbd> do nothing. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> just exits. I also did `gem install compass` to see if it would autoload it and not ask me anymore, but it didn't work.

Comment: I have edited this post for readability (primarily that means I formatted the console output as a code block). Posts that are cleanly formatted are much more likely to attract answers, so I hope this helps you. You can learn more about how to format posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Thank you for the edit and sorry for the poor formatting. I will read that right away !

Comment: @DanLowe You set a good example for how to nicely inform a newcomer about SO's customs and standards.

Comment: I am facing the same issue, @Eduard did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

This issue is only faced on Git Bash windows that uses `mingw64`, trying the same on Windows Command Prompt (cmd) works perfectly